# Delete a UILocalnotification at a certain indexpath

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification, uiapplication, nsindexpath

I have a bunch of UILocalNotifications but I only want to delete a certain one at a given indexpath, therefor

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

wont work out for me. I know I can use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:UILocalNotification];
```

but how do I get the UILocalNotification from the given NSIndexPath?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can get an array of scheduled notification from: `@property(nonatomic,copy) NSArray *scheduledLocalNotifications`

Get the one you want by the index number of your choosing and then pass the UILocalNotification* to `- (void)cancelLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification`.