# Clearing notification from Notification Center

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

My app schedules a UILocalNotification in the background, which is added to Notification Center. However, when the notification is tapped in Notification Center, the app is opens, but the notification remains in Notification Center. How can it be removed please?

Comment: Similar to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545292/delete-a-uilocalnotification-at-a-certain-indexpath)

Comment: No, I do not want to cancel the notification. I want to clear it from Notification Center (which one pulls down from the top of the screen) after the user has tapped on it and the app has been launched

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773584/can-i-programmatically-clear-my-apps-notifications-from-the-ios-5-notification)

Comment: Actually your first link turned out to be what I needed. If you post it as an answer I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: this doesn;t clear the notification, just deletes it. If you have a repeat interval in place 'next fire date' will no longer fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cancel a UILocalNotification use:

```
- (void)cancelLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification.
```

Source: [Delete a UILocalnotification at a certain indexpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545292/delete-a-uilocalnotification-at-a-certain-indexpath)